# How to debug Linux hang?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded

We are using beagle bone black based custom board, with kernel version 3.12.
We are facing system hang during one of the init script,(Which brings up WiFi)
this hang happens after random number of power cycle,

`Nothing works during this hang, it looks like system is frozen, It doesn't even respond to sysrq keys`

I assume this to be in the ISR code because of which none of the thing works.

Unluckily When we enable 'Detect hung task(`DETECT_HUNG_TASK`)' we don't see the issue. :(

Only thing works is if watchdog is enabled after watchdog timer expires it reboots the system and system recovers.

However we want to find out where the issue is.

Any suggestion?

I thought of using softdog and repair script pair to print some messages but I assume external interrupt will have higher priority and when it executes and hangs in there, softdog timer will also not get a chance to execute right ?

Randomness of the bug makes it much more difficult to debug :(

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you look carefully at the logs when you rebooted after it hung?

Comment: Yes, We don't see anything there :( We doubt WiFI over SDIO driver, but we are not sure about it. Because when we don't load WiFi driver module we don't see it. However sometimes we don't see it even when it is enabled.

Comment: @JuliePelletier Logs usually cannot be written after a hard hang, similar to kernel panic

Comment: Did you try to redirect console to serial, and boot the kernel with `loglevel=7` without `quiet` (if any)? Are there some obscure messages from kernel were coming?

Comment: Add the Wifi make/chipset to the question please.

Comment: `DETECT_HUNG_TASK` is usually for userspace tasks that hang inside system call. If hang comes from kernel code (for example, driver), it is useless.

Comment: @siblynx I am having access to serial log we don't see anything on serial console:(

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro It is Marvel's Wifi chip is 88W8801-NMD2.

Comment: @siblynx :o I thought `DETECT_HUNG_TASK` is for detecting kernel hangs. I tried `LOCKUP_DETECTOR` also with that also I don't see any log messages. :(

Comment: Does it lockup without wi-fi?

Comment: We haven't seen lockup without WiFi driver. However when we enable any kernel hacking option that time also we don't see lock up. So, though we suspect WiFi the most we are not 100% sure about it.

Comment: You can try to use `kgdb` together with `gdb` on a neighbor machine, but it's hard to tell will kernel even tell anything to `gdb` or it will just hang and nothing useful you will get.

Comment: We thought about it but as kernel is not responding to sysrq we are kind of doubtful about kgdb, one more reason is we are not able to ping device after lockup.

Comment: If watchdog is resetting then your kernel is simply "panicked" without the panic, i.e. stopped working. So the board simply dislike your kernel for a reason one of: wrong configuration, wrong instructions that kernel uses or wrong registers it manipulates. If it lockup inside Wi-Fi driver then you will need to seek for a bug inside it. If you modified the driver somehow then audit your changes. It's hard to tell specifically without further information about the board being on hands.

Comment: Hmm let me re-look the driver and its patches.

Comment: make the driver in question loadable and see if it hangs only after modprobe of that particular driver. once it is isolated, use printks

Comment: its already a loadable module, and if I put printks issues doesn't appear :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, We did code reading as it was being suggested in the comments and found the section of the patch where system may go into infinite loop(in irq) and won't come out of it.

However when we put printk in that irq function issue was not getting reproduced. (timing issue you know!)

So finally my colleague tried old school method of toggling GPIO and it helped. That was also difficult as more than two entries of GPIO toggle would prevent reproducing issue.

inside function he used GPIO toggle as follows,

```
func()
{  
   //set gpio high
     some doubtfull code..
     ....
   //set gpio low
}
```

That's how he tracked the problematic code and its solution is available in linux-4.1 he fixed it and he is testing it.

@ShankarSM:If you are reading this, all credit goes to you for tracking down it :-)