# How to debug a completely stuck kernel?

Tags: fedora, linux-kernel, debugging

Running kernel 4.15 here from F27. Since I moved a week ago from 4.13 to 4.15, a highly threaded app I have been developing started to hang the kernel. Not always, but most of the times. I have an i7 cpu with 8 cores, 16 threads. When running my app with several threads, usually > 20, sooner or later I get my machine to hang and only a hard reboot will shutdown the PC.

Unfortunately there's no info in journalctl to analyze once I reboot the PC.

How can I understand what's going on to be able to report a bug or fix my app?

Comment: 2 things to get you started: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key (see the crashdump & backtrace keys) & google for "linux crashdump"

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287890/how-to-debug-linux-hang

Comment: It'd be great presenting some logs (perhaps from the app itself or diagnosis tools) or even a minimal set of lines of code representing the app's core behavior.